# how do i disable url modification by users for security reasons?

Tags: url, url-rewriting

Supose a  url  is  like this www.anyurl.com?ut=44354454 if somebody  change  it  to
www.anyurl.com?ut=44354 then  get variable  will  change but i have seen  some  sites in  which  even  if  you change the query string in url  it still lands to  the same  page.
This should be so  as  to manage security